# Normal map seams at uv borders

Tags: opengl, math, graphics, directx

When I use Normal maps in my app I get seams like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL5II.jpg)

I think there is something wrong with tangents 
I compute them whit this function from Rastertek.com

```
vector1[0] = vertex2.x - vertex1.x;
vector1[1] = vertex2.y - vertex1.y;
vector1[2] = vertex2.z - vertex1.z;

vector2[0] = vertex3.x - vertex1.x;
vector2[1] = vertex3.y - vertex1.y;
vector2[2] = vertex3.z - vertex1.z;

tuVector[0] = vertex2.tu - vertex1.tu;
tvVector[0] = vertex2.tv - vertex1.tv;

tuVector[1] = vertex3.tu - vertex1.tu;
tvVector[1] = vertex3.tv - vertex1.tv;

den = 1.0f / (tuVector[0] * tvVector[1] - tuVector[1] * tvVector[0]);

tangent.x = (tvVector[1] * vector1[0] - tvVector[0] * vector2[0]) * den;
tangent.y = (tvVector[1] * vector1[1] - tvVector[0] * vector2[1]) * den;
tangent.z = (tvVector[1] * vector1[2] - tvVector[0] * vector2[2]) * den;

binormal.x = (tuVector[0] * vector2[0] - tuVector[1] * vector1[0]) * den;
binormal.y = (tuVector[0] * vector2[1] - tuVector[1] * vector1[1]) * den;
binormal.z = (tuVector[0] * vector2[2] - tuVector[1] * vector1[2]) * den;
```

I use Vertex normals but there is no difference when I use face normals i get the same picture

How can I solve this problem

This is picture of normal map rendered in diffuse texture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28qZi.jpg)

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Do you have the link to the page on Rastertek.com where you got the code.

Comment: My first though is that the texture map does not join up correctly. Can you make a model where the texture map is just applied to the object as a normal texture and the simple face/vertex normals.

Comment: Also, make sure that you use `GL_REPEAT` for the texture wrap mode.

Comment: http://rastertek.com/dx11tut20.html

Comment: OK i have done it I see the same seams at normal map but I dont think it is issue I tried to render this model in Marmoset toolbag and there is ok

Comment: I created normal map in Zbrush 4R7 with Smooth uvs and smooth normals on

Comment: Looking closely at the rendered output, it looks like the for the top right you have a reversed sense of lighting. In the bottom left it looks like you have groves on the surface, in the top right it looks like they point outwards. This might indicate problems with orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking closely at the rendered output, it looks like the for the top right you have a reversed sense of lighting. In the bottom left it looks like you have groves on the surface, in the top right it looks like they point outwards. This might indicate problems with orientation.

Actually looking at the  normal map rendered in diffuse texture you have the same boundaries. Before proceeding make sure the "normal map rendered in diffuse texture" appears seamless.

Spheres are tricky as you can not define a non vanishing vector field over the whole sphere. (The [Hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem)) This means you can not consistently define the tangent and binormal vectors over the whole sphere, there must be some jumps. This may not a great problem for you as normal map is made up of individual pieces. It may be possible to alter the sense of vectors `tu` and `tv` for each piece. So for some pieces one or other is reversed `tu'=-tu`, `tv'=-tv`, or possibly the order of the two is reversed. `tu'=tv, tv'=-tu`. You will need some way of the code knowing which patch needs which transformation.

One drastic way around the problem is to remove the top and bottom from you object. This will allow you to treat the object as a distorted cylinder which can have consistent definitions for the two vectors.

Perhaps a better solution might be to store the normal map as a three component, directly giving 3D normal at each point.

Assuming we don't have to worry about rotations other than 90º we can have the symmetry of the square

1. No change   tu'=tu,   tv'=tv
2. Reflection in tu=0  tu'=-tu,  tv'=tv
3. Reflection in tv=0  tu'=tu,   tv'=-tv
4. Rotation 90º   tu'=-tv,  tv'=tu
5. Rotation -90º  tu'=tv,  tv'=-tu
6. Rotation 180º  tu=-tu, tv'=-tv
7. Reflection in tu=tv,  tu'=tv, tv'=tu
8. Reflection in tu=-tv,  tu'=-tv, tv'=-tu

Comment: OK thanks a lot  . Is it only for spherical and torrus models or I mast Calculate all my models like that???

Comment: Please can you add all possible tu ,tv transformations

Comment: hairy ball problem? reading about that sooner, couldve saved me ALOT of time